# Allow https links as valid when adding a new answer to Stack Exchange section

Tags: bug, status-deferred, profile-page, hyperlinks, ssl

When you go to your profile and want to add a link to an answer on Stack Exchange you can paste a custom URL to an answer. If that starts with `https` you get the message that this does not link to an answer, if you remove the 's' it works.

Does not work:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417633/mvn-install-fails-due-to-incompatible-types/8418109#8418109
```

Works:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417633/mvn-install-fails-due-to-incompatible-types/8418109#8418109
```

Comment: I had no idea `https` was supported at all! Sweet!

Comment: If you use Firefox use HTTPS Everywhere and HTTPS Finder and HTTPS glory awaits you on so many sites... Have fun!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While we are slowly rolling out SSL infrastructure for the network the work hasn't been completed so I can't accept https links yet.

---

"Slowly" is the key word here.  We've rolled out SSL on openid.stackexchange.com and careers, and are rolling it out on stackexchange.com and api.stackexchange.com as part of API V2.

We're proofing our SSL infrastructure, basically.  Once we've got a nice track record of scaling it we'll start looking at turning it on for the behemoths that are the Q&A sites.

Comment: +1 for rolling out SSL!!! I feel like giving you a 500 point bounty just for that.

Comment: I understand that. +1 for working on SSL! could you change your validator to ignore the protocol and always assume http? I can live with a http link but when you paste a long url one cannot see that it starts with https and so doesn't think about changing it (I just copied the url from my profile page so it took me two days to figure out why it wont work). Or just add a different warning (say: 'https not allowed here' Instead of 'There is no answer at that url')

Comment: @Kevin: You could accept https links as valid and [correct the certificate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites), while continuing to redirect to http until you've proofed the scalability. This would be an achievable stepping stone towards full SSL support.

Comment: Any updates on this? I use https everywhere and was hoping for support

Comment: I'd also like to see support for this.