# Certificate errors on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, error-message

When I vist the main https://stackexchange.com/ site, IE9 blocks the display of content using an invalid security certificate, as indicated on the infobar at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Secure connections are still an ongoing project for SE. They've explained this [elsewhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115367/141525). They're slowly working on it, so you can't expect everything to be working yet.

Comment: Do you mean `https://stackexchange.com/`?

Comment: No. I mean http.

Comment: No repro, IE 9.0.8112.16421

Comment: Happens to me every time I click my "network profile" ink. IE9 on win 7. Not an https connection, but a yellow "blocked" bar about sites with invalid certificates.

Comment: Are there even certificates for the HTTP protocol? Seems pretty pointless...

Comment: The Stack Exchange site does link to secure resources for **both regular and secured connections** (for some reason). Although simply clicking the "show whatever" button in the yellow box permanently cleared the issue for me. I think it's just IE saying "why are we loading secure things from a non-secure page?" Perhaps I got a different error.

Comment: @Dennis, A page you navigate to via http may make references to other content using https.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: I see. JQuery and OpenID.

Comment: I get this in IE8 on one computer but not IE8 on another computer. Strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://stackexchange.com no longer serves https content on http pages. Thanks for the report.